# How to save a value for later use in travis ci notification message

Tags: travis-ci

I try to customize my travis CI notification template a little bit.

Since I'm working on a java / maven project, I want to extract the current version from the pom file.

This can be done with

```
mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec
```

Than I would like to add this extracted version number from pom file to the notification that will be send by travis.

```
notifications:
  email: false
  slack
    template
        - '%{repository} %{EXTRACTED_POM_VERSION} #%{build_number} (%{branch} - %{commit} : %{author}): %{message} (<a href="%{build_url}">Details</a>/<a href="%{compare_url}">Change view</a>)'
```

Any idea if this is possible and how this could be done? Maybe as exported global variable

Comment: "exported global variable": you're getting somewhere. Another possibility: put that command right where the variable would be.

Comment: what do you mean with: put that command right where the variable would be. Could you give me an example?

Comment: In `notifications.slack.template` (like where you've got one now): `"%{repository} $(mvn -q -Dexec.executable="echo" -Dexec.args='${project.version}' --non-recursive exec:exec) #%{build_number} (%{branch} - %{commit} : %{author}): %{message} (<a href=\"%{build_url}\">Details</a>/<a href=\"%{compare_url}\">Change view</a>)"`, maybe?

Comment: That doesn't work ... Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately not